# Rest Assured - Getting Operation Timed Out Error while testing using RestAssured. But The same endpoint working fine in browser

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have an endpoint to be tested using `RestAssured`. The same endpoint is working fine while opening it in browser/Postman. But, while trying to test the same using `RestAssured`,

I am getting `Operation Timed Out Error`.

I had to connect to proxy to make that end point working in browser. used the same proxy in the rest assured also.

Sample Code below:

```
given().proxy("My_Proxy_URL_HERE",8080).when().get("My_API_URL_Here").then().log().all();
```

I am getting the response as

> "Operation Timed Out" with Status Code 503.

I need your suggestion, what could be the possible issue, how to debug etc. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which IDE are you using ? Did you add the proxy settings to your IDE ? 
You don't have to define the proxy in your code .proxy()

Answer (score 2):

There can be many reasons for this behavior:

- The address is just wrong and given there is some load balancer/proxy it can be configured to wait for a certain period of time and then respond with 503 status code.
  Note, 503 is not a "request timed out", but "Service Unavailable".
- The request url is good, but the request lacks some headers so that the load balancer/proxy won't be able to route the request to the required server.

How to check this? there exist tools that can come handy in this situation:

1. Check the access logs of the load balancer/proxy and even of your server if its possible - and see the request.
2. If it doesn't help, try to compare requests coming from rest-assured vs regular request. You can use tools like [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp) for example, there are others, or you can even roll your own.

The idea is simple:
Start the "interceptor" on some port of your local computer (say, 9999 for example)

Configure the interceptor to forward all the requests to proxy of your choice (identified by URL - My_Proxy_URL_HERE and port 8080).
Now rest-assured must call localhost:9999 and the request will be intercepted by this tool. You'll be able to inspect its contents - headers, body, http method - everything.
Do the same for browser request and compare.